# resize relative layout after adding child view

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

I got a custom view extending RelativeLayout.
After inflating it with an xml layout I want to add another view to it.
I want to add the view above the existing one.
That seems to work but the RelativeLayout does not resize itself.
It looks like the older contents get overwritten, or maybe scroll down, where they
are not visible.

I create my custom RelativeLayout with:

public class BottomBarEdit extends RelativeLayout {

```
private Context context;


public BottomBarEdit(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;

    View.inflate(context, R.layout.lay_bottom_bar_edit, this);
```

I try to add a view dynamically with:

```
// create layout parameters
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.bottom_bar_buttons);
    // RelativeLayout editMain = (RelativeLayout)
    // findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar_edit);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View noteBar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_bottom_bar_notes, null);

    this.addView(noteBar, lparams);
```

Any idea whats going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I've the same question. But you should show us your layout xmls too.